# replace String with date from resultset in java

Tags: java

could someone assist as to why enddate is not being replaced from the resultset in the below code.

```
    .replace("ZZZZ", String.valueOf(enddate)));
```

Message gets returned as "**Bid closes at ZZZZ . Continue bidding** "

Thanks

```
    String productcode = null;
    Date enddate = null;

        while (resultSet.next()) {

            productcode = resultSet.getString("productcode");
            enddate = resultSet.getTimestamp("enddate");

            message = ReturnTexts
                    .getMessage(connection, "BROADCAST")
                    .replace(
                            "YYYY",
                            String.valueOf(maxBid(productcode, connection))
                                    .replace("ZZZZ",
                                            String.valueOf(enddate)));
```

Comment: depends upon content from maxBid(). what it is returning ?

Comment: hi sanjeev..maxBid() is returning well the max amount but when i try to replace enddate i get Bid closes at ZZZZ . Continue bidding. You have given me an idea and i got it solved

Comment: If you have solved it, can you please post your solution as an answer, for the benefit of the next person to have a similar issue?

Comment: i added a bracket in this code ")" and time is now being displayed(2014-02-25 04:17:22.) well                        .replace( "YYYY",               String.valueOf(maxBid(productcode, connection)))
        .replace("ZZZZ",
            String.valueOf(enddate));

Comment: @pmaingi Please post your solution in that big "Your Answer" box down below rather than as a comment. And it is perfectly okay for you to accept your own answer, which tells the reader that you consider the question solved and closed.

Answer (score 0):

i added a bracket in this code ")" and time is now being displayed(2014-02-25 04:17:22.) well

```
    String.valueOf(maxBid(productcode, connection))**)**
                                .replace("ZZZZ",
                                         String.valueOf(enddate));
```